# Can I create a custom form in Suitelet using Bootstrap for Netsuite?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, netsuite

Suitelet defalt form is ugly. I want to create a custom form using bootstrap for suitelet in Netsuite. Can I do that? I want to display this bootstrap form using html with suitelet.

e.g for a bootstrap form

```
    <form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can I fetch the get value of the form using suitlet default get API

```
    var email= request.getParameter('email');
    var name = request.getParameter('name');       

    var newCust = nlapiCreateRecord('customer');
    newCust.setFieldValue('xxxx', name);
    newCust.setFieldValue('xxxx', email);
    var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(newCust);
```

Comment: I found the answer and I have created a little tutorial at my blog here http://www.anuragkumar.in/2016/02/how-to-create-custom-form-in-html-for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your own HTML/CSS, you should be able to get the values using `request.getBody()`. You should then parse the response body to fetch the values from form.

Alternatively, you can write a client-side javascript, which sets the URL parameters and its values on `submit` event, then you would be able to get the values using `request.getParameter()` APIs.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out, I created this Suitelet in Suitescript 2.0. Its a hack but works fine. Just add your POST conditionals to grab the data from the form.
https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/loading-custom-html-and-bootstrap-within-a-suitelet-form/

[image: End result]

Comment: It's looking great

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular form post with `action` method pointing to your suitescript end point and on the other side you can get the values with `request.getAllParameters()`.

e.g

HTML:

```
 <form role="form" action = "https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=1&compid=XXXXXX&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" method ="POST">
```

Suitescript:

```
 var params = request.getAllParameters();
 var email= params['email'];
 var name = params['name'];
```