# how can i add form-control bootstrap in netsuite forms

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite

i am trying to create a custom HTML form in netsuite. i have created the form in html with bootstrap but for giving style to input controls( ). is it possible to give bootstrap style to it . please help me

Comment: Do you meant changing a NetSuite form to use bootstrap instead of its native NetSuite styling?

Comment: https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/loading-custom-html-and-bootstrap-within-a-suitelet-form/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403519/can-i-create-a-custom-form-in-suitelet-using-bootstrap-for-netsuite

Comment: im using a simple html form, in that i want to add some bootstrap css. without hack code cant we achieve this.